# It is possible to send callback param from service class android (native module) into react native

Tags: android, react-native

I have a service called `myService.java` and it will be run interval

the code is :

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Service jalan", "beneran dah");
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
            List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();
            List<Contact> cont = db.auditid();
            for (Contact cn : contacts)
            {
                int idsql = cn.getID();
                if(String.valueOf(cn.getFlag()).equals("0")){
                    Log.d("Id", String.valueOf(cn.getID()) + " Flag :" + cn.getFlag());
                    sending a  = new sending();
                    a.execute();
                }
            }
            for (Contact cn : cont)
            {
                String idaud = cn.getName(); // here is getting id from sqlite
                Log.d("Service get", idaud);
                sendget b = new sendget();
                b.execute();
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 120 * 1000);
        }
    };
    mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 120 * 1000);
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

and in native module I've using this code to create callback:

```
@ReactMethod
public void startTrackService(Callback successCallback) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(reactContext, myService.class);
    reactContext.startService(intent);
    successCallback.invoke("testing service");
}
```

for JS file, I call the function above with :

```
let dataAdd = NativeModules.SqliteModule
dataAdd.startTrackService(function (value){
    console.log("Service callback " + value);
})
```

but the logcat just showing `I/ReactNativeJS: Service callback testing service` once,

there's a way to sending callback from service to JS, so my callback will sending the `id` just be like a service running interval to JS file?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: no i'm not yet solved, I just ask my mate to change workflow to handling it on react native